# Find the no open cursor without DBA Access

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I am getting

> java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01000: maximum open cursors exceeded"

error. I want to know the no of open cursors in my Db. I don't have DBA access. I have written the following procedure to delete the thousands/lac of record from DB:

```
"create or replace //creating procedure
PROCEDURE SUBSREMOVAL AS 
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('----DELETING ROW FROM table1 TABLE START------' );
  DELETE from  table1 c where c.X in (select t.Y from table2 t);//delete query
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('----DELETING ROW FROM table1 TABLE END------' );
  COMMIT;
END SUBSREMOVAL"  //ending procedure
```

Comment: "*maximum open cursors exceeded"*  typically means you are not closing your `Statement` or `PreparedStatement` instances properly. You need to show us the Java code that generates the problem. **[edit]** your question do **not** post code or additional information as comments

Comment: *Again*: do **not** post code in comments. [edit] your question.